# Restrict rest api response based on created date

Tags: rest, salesforce

I am passing following request using rest api

```
/services/data/v27.0/chatter/feeds/news/me/feed-items
```

which return me all the feed items records. How can I restrict the response for getting only those feed items which are created in last month?

Comment: What does the API documentation tell you?

Comment: I did'nt get anything specific in documentation yet to restrict response.

Comment: Do the returned items have any property that allows you to filter the list after fetching it?

Comment: In doc "relative​CreatedDate" term is mentioned but not sure how to use it. here is the link. http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/chatterapi/Content/connect_responses_feed_item.htm

Comment: "createdDate" is coming in returned item.